# Using lapply and an anonymous function in a list of data frames

Tags: r, lapply

In a list of data frames `listdf` , I want to determine the mean, max, min, stdv and the number or rows (number of values) for the column Concentration in each data frame :

```
mean <- lapply(listdf, function(x) {mean(x$Concentration, na.rm = F)})
max <- lapply(listdf, function(x) {max(x$Concentration, na.rm = F)})
min <- lapply(listdf, function(x) {min(x$Concentration, na.rm = F)})
sd <- lapply(listdf, function(x) {sd(x$Concentration, na.rm = F)})
nbr <- lapply(listdf, function(x) {nrow(x$Concentration, na.rm = F)})
```

However, `nrow` does not work with `lapply` and a function. How can I modify it ?

Also, is it possible to add (via `lapply` and a function or `tibble` ?) an additional sixth list of analysis for `listdf` to tell that the number of rejected data frames in `listdf` is "NA" ? I know it because I selected in `listdf` all the data frames without rejected values, but I wish to add this step in the script for further analysis.

```
nbr_rejected <- lapply(listdf, ??? "NA") 

(nbr_rejected="NA")
```

Comment: Try `sum(!is.na(x$Concentration))` instead of `nrow(x$Concentration, na.rm = F)`

Comment: I don't quite understand what the second question is. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try to elaborate more the second question. From my list of data frames `listdf`, I have now 5 lists, giving the mean, max, min,... of the column Concentration of each DF. Now I wish to have a sixth list telling that the number of rejected values in each DF is "NA". It is not the calculation of specific values _per se_ , just a list with (nrow= number of DF in `listdf`) each time the character "NA"

Comment: Is this the number of NAs in each of the data frames?

Comment: No, imagine just that I want to add another list (1 column and nrow=length of `listdf`) with each time the characters "the sky is blue" written for each row

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `length`:

```
a <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
lapply(a, function(x) {length(x$hp[!is.na(x$hp)])})
```

**EDIT**
Your second question:

```
a <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
lapply(a, function(x) {data.frame(value = matrix(NA, nrow(x), 1))})
```